# CiviCRM and OSX Local Installation with WordPress

Tags: local

I am trying to install CiviCRM 5.45.0 on my local computer so I can test out some new things and learn how to use it. I am trying to install a fresh version. I can install and activate the plugin but when I go to configure it I get the following error first

[image]

there are several like these, I assume it can't load XML's that are related to the extensions I was trying to install?
[image]

[image]

and then if I refresh the screen I get this

[image]

I am using the following setup in my Local

[image]

[image]

and my database privileges for that user look like this

[image]

Has anyone set this up using this setup no a Mac before? Any ideas what I am missing? Something I am missing in my PHP Extensions?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using MAMP or something similar to provide a LAMP stack on your Mac?

Comment: @Graham I am using Local Version 6.1.8+5621.

Comment: OK, not used that. The error messages indicate that at least some DB tables appear to be missing. I'm wondering if the install process has worked properly. Can you see all of your database tables using something like phpmyadmin?

Comment: @Graham No, it looks like the Civi tables are not being written during the install process, something is stopping it. I assume this is when they should be created, right. During the install process, just not sure what is stopping them from being created I guess. Maybe once I get that figured out they would install and the installation process would move forward.

Comment: I don't know how critical the Local Version tool is to your workflow. I do know that https://www.mamp.info/en/mac/ will work in terms of installing a new WP/Civi site on a Mac as I've used it myself.